# reading values for the layout from JSON file

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I want to parse a JSON file generated by my RESTful application and use values from that file in order to change some variables of the `layout/style.xml` like the color of the background. I really need some help with it.

Comment: I recommend you to google it. there are plenty of samples targeting what you intend to do.

Comment: I can't find anything like that that's why I've asked : /

Comment: To give you a little hint: You just parse the style JSON in your Android application, get all values you want to change in `style.xml` and then parse `style.xml` with a XML parser, change the variables with the JSON variables and finally serialize the changed objects again with a XML serializer (whereas some frameworks are parser and serializer in one).

Comment: Is there any more efficient way to do that?Because I want to be able to load different screens and calculate response time.What I've thought is to change the values of the xml programatically but It's not a good practice.Thank for the hint @PaulEngstler

Comment: Well, if you can solve the following problem it's going to be faster: Somehow your application needs to know "where" values need to be changed. If you parse your XML you can easily access those objects because you can easily access/iterate them. However If you don't do that you need to "know" where to change values (like exact line numbers and so on). If you're worried about speed implement it first and measure the execution time. Also use fast parsing frameworks like  gson (as strongmayer suggested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert your JSON file to java objects you can use gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). On the other hand the layout/style.xml file cannot be modified in run-time. If you want to change the background color or any other UI property in run-time you have to do it programatically. For example you can define all the necessary styles in your layout/style.xml and when you converted your JSON file into java objects with gson, you can apply the corresponding style depending on the JSON response.